# Compressing existing mail files, readable in Roundcube (dovecot, centos)

Tags: compression, centos7, zlib, dovecot, roundcube

Roundcube can read compressed files without the extension c.f. example below:

```
-rwxr-x---   1 vmail vmail 5170815 Jun 20 10:14 1529504317.M895396P3597.mailstore-clone,S=7142774,W=7235655:2,S
```

Using the `file` command on the same file returns:

```
1529504317.M895396P3597.mailstore-clone,S=7142774,W=7235655:2,S: gzip compressed data, from Unix
```

New files are being compressed using zlib plugin, and I need to compress all the remaining old mail files so they will be still readable in Roundcube. Is it possible to somehow activate zlib plugin on existing mails already in the inbox?

Comment: As far as compression occurs at delivery stage old messages can't be delivered again and compressed by zlib plugin. But you always can traverse the maildir by `find` utility and compress implicitly every file that is not compressed by plugin.

Comment: There is `file` utility that can analyze file content an determine whether the file is already compressed by gzip or not. Messages compressed by gzip plugin has no `.gzip` extension so you have to perform indirect checkout.

Comment: Small layouts and grammar improvements.